# Building a calculator in java (with a switch)

Tags: java

I am using a switch to calculate two numbers, but when i try to do any sort of operator i just keep getting `0`.

```
//imports
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
      public static void main (String[] args) {
//get first number
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the first number: > ");
        int num1 = scan.nextInt();
// get second number
        System.out.println("Please enter the second number: > ");
        int num2 = scan.nextInt();
// what the user wants to do
        System.out.println("Please enter the method you would like to use "
                + "(+ , - , * , / , ^ ) > " );
        String method = scan.next();
        char operation = method.charAt(0);
        String output = "";
//switch for first number
        switch(num1) {
                case 0: output+= "zero";
                        break;
                case 1: output+= " one";
                        break;
                case 2: output+= " two";
                        break;
                case 3: output+= " three";
                        break;
                case 4: output+= " four";
                        break;
                case 5: output+= " five";
                        break;
                case 6: output+= " six";
                        break;
                case 7: output+= " seven";
                        break;
                case 8: output+= " eight";
                        break;
                case 9: output+= " nine";
                        break;
                case 10: output+= " ten";
                        break;
}
// operation the user wants to use
      switch (operation){
          case '+' : output += " plus";
                     break;
          case '-' : output += " minus";
                     break;
          case '*' : output += " times";
                     break;
          case '/' : output += " divided by";
                     break;
          case '^' : output += " to the power of";
                     break;
}
//switch for second number
       switch (num2) {
               case 0: output += " zero";
                       break;
               case 1: output += " one";
                       break;
               case 2: output += " two";
                       break;
               case 3: output += " three";
                       break;
               case 4: output += " four";
                       break;
               case 5: output += " five";
                       break;
               case 6: output += " six";
                       break;
               case 7: output += " seven";
                       break;
               case 8: output += " eight";
                       break;
               case 9: output += " nine";
                       break;
               case 10: output += " ten";
                       break;
// calculate the answer
        }
          int answer = 0 ;
       switch (answer) {
           case '+' : answer = (answer + (num1 + num2));
               break;
           case '-' : answer = (answer + (num1 - num2));
               break;
           case '*' : answer = (answer + (num1 * num2));
               break;
           case '/' : answer = (answer + (num1 / num2));
               break;
           case '^' : answer = (answer + (int) (Math.pow(num1,num2) ));
               break;
       }
       System.out.println(output + " equals " + answer );
    }
}
```

Im pretty sure that my problem is at the bottom of the program with the actual function

```
 int answer = 0 ;
       switch (answer) {
```

Starting somewhere around that area, just having a hard time figuring it out. Maybe somebody else can give input as to what i am doing wrong

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 6):

```
   int answer = 0 ;
   switch (answer) {
```

doesn't make any sense, you are switching on `0` (hardcoded) and you don't have relevant case,

switch on `operation` instead

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to do

```
switch (operation) {
```

instead of

```
switch (answer) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening:

You are assigning `0` to `answer`. Then:

- if `answer` is `'+'`, do the first thing
- if `answer` is `'-'`, do some other thing
- if `answer` is `'*'`, do some third thing
- ...

Clearly you can see this is absurd; the only case that could possible trigger is if you had `'\0'` (null character) as one of the cases.

It would seem like you would want to switch on `operation`, not `answer`.

Answer (score 0):

you are saying:

```
...
int answer = 0;
if(answer == '+'){
    ...
}
else if(answer ==  '-'){
    ...
}
else if(answer == '*'){
    ...
} ...
```

i suppose this should work:

```
   int answer = 0 ;
   switch (operation) {
       case '+' : answer = num1 + num2;
           break;
       case '-' : answer = num1 - num2;
           break;
       case '*' : answer = num1 * num2;
           break;
       case '/' : answer = num1 / num2;
           break;
       case '^' : answer = (int) Math.pow(num1,num2) ;
           break;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String args []){

        int x=10,y=5,add,sub,div,mul;

        switch (4) {
        case 1:
            add=x+y;
            System.out.print("add :"+add);
            break;
        case 2:
            sub=x-y;
            System.out.print("sub :"+sub);
            break;
        case 3:
            mul=x*y;
            System.out.print("mul:"+mul);
            break;
        case 4:
            div=x/y;
            System.out.print("div:"+div);           
        default:
            System.out.print("invailid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain a bit your answer, giving only code is not really helpful for anyone to really understand what was their mistakes.

Comment: What on earth is "switch(4)" anyways?